# Issues with values-cs string.xml file

Tags: android

I have translated in-app strings to czech language and I am getting strange compilation error in it. I have also set encoding to utf-8 by right clicking on file in project explorer of Eclipse. The contents of values-cs/strings.xml are:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string name="app_name">Víte že?</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Nastavení</string>
    <string name="hello_world">Ahoj světe!</string>
    <string name="share">Sdílet</string>
    <string name="swipe_vertical">Přejeďte vertikálně posunout</string>
    <string name="single_tap">Kliknout pro zvětšení písma</string>
    <string name="double_tap">Kliknout dvojitě pro zmenšení písma</string>
    <string name="swipe_next">Přejeďtě zleva doprava pro další//předcházející citaci</string>
    <string name="got_it">Mám to</string>
    <string name="touch_remove">Dotknout se pro vymazání z oblíbených</string>
​    <string name="set_font">Táhnout pro nastavení velikosti písma</string>
​    <string name="no_items">Žádné citace v oblíbených</string>
​    <string name="swipe_remove">Přejeďte přes položku pro odstranění z oblíených</string>
​    <string name="rate">Ohodnotit</string>
    <string name="ifyouenjoy">Pokud se Vám aplikace líbí</string>
    <string name="plsrate">Prosím ohodnoťte. Děkujeme za podporu!</string>
    <string name="remind">Upozornit později</string>

</resources>
```

Error: error: Found text "
Line no: 13

any help?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have some characters before each line in your `string.xml` due to a copy/past method.

Can you try to reformat your code by placing your text cursor at the beginning of each line and delete to return to previous line ?

Replace your `string.xml` with below `formatted` content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string name="app_name">Víte že?</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Nastavení</string>
    <string name="hello_world">Ahoj světe!</string>
    <string name="share">Sdílet</string>
    <string name="swipe_vertical">Přejeďte vertikálně posunout</string>
    <string name="single_tap">Kliknout pro zvětšení písma</string>
    <string name="double_tap">Kliknout dvojitě pro zmenšení písma</string>
    <string name="swipe_next">Přejeďtě zleva doprava pro další//předcházející citaci</string>
    <string name="gotit">Mám to</string><string name="toucremove">asfadf</string>
    <string name="setfont">Táhnout pro nastavení velikosti písma</string>
    <string name="no_items">Žádné citace v oblíbených</string>
    <string name="swipe_remove">Přejeďte přes položku pro odstranění z oblíených</string>
    <string name="rate">Ohodnotit</string>
    <string name="ifyouenjoy">Pokud se Vám aplikace líbí</string>
    <string name="plsrate">Prosím ohodnoťte. Děkujeme za podporu!</string>
    <string name="remind">Upozornit později</string>

</resources>
```